# Wifi no longer connecting automatically

Tags: wireless

Is there a way to reinstall my wifi... utilities or whatever? Suddenly every time I open my laptop lid to bring it out from sleep, it no longer connects to my wifi. It doesn't even see the SSID. I have to click on "Enable Wifi" to disable it, then enable it, then select my wifi.

Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron 1750.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run this command from the terminal:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Find out your wireless driver. Here is an example:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 35
   serial: xx:94:6b:99:55:xx
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-29-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

In my example, it reports, *driver=iwlwifi*. Yours will probably be different.

In most cases, you can use the driver you found directly in the next step. However, if your driver is reported as wl0, then use wl. If it reports b43-bcma-bridge, then use bcma.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add a single line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"
```

Of course, substitute the driver you found, if not iwlwifi. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

How does it work now?

Comment: Working good so far. Wifi seems connected before I even log in where before it used to (if it connected automatically at all) take about 10-15 seconds. I had iwlwifi too only my version is 3.13.0-39-generic. Thank you...